# XmlSlurper converts html encoded symbols

Tags: xml, parsing, gradle, groovy

```
def xmlNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><b>&#8240;</b>')
println XmlUtil.serialize(xmlNode)
```

Prints next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b>
  ‰
</b>
```

Is there way to prevent converting `&#8240;` into `‰`? `XmlSlurper` documentation says nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a POC overriding `XmlSlurper.characters` to handle the character entity. Apache commons `StringEscapeUtils` was also needed to convert `‰` back to entity code:

```
@Grab(group='commons-lang', module='commons-lang', version='2.6')

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils as SE
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def parser = new XmlSlurper() {
    void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length)  {
        def entity = SE.escapeXml(buffer[start].toString())
        super.characters entity.toCharArray(), start, entity.size() 
    }
}

def xml = parser.parseText '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><b>&#8240;</b>'

def serialized = SE.unescapeXml( XmlUtil.serialize(xml) )
assert '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><b>&#8240;</b>\n' == serialized
```

Note this is handling a single character, you may need to tweak it a bit if you need multicharacter handling. Also note that in the `assert` a line break was needed. It was added by `XmlUtil.serialize`

No idea if it's the best way to do that, though.

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. But trying to load data from xml file and `super.characters` throws exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Probably it's because extra formatting chars. `buffer[start].toString()` contains empty string. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You might need `buffer[start..length-1] as String` or something like that. You can add some `println` in your code or post the whole XML so we can identify which char is throwing the errors.